High order parabolic PDEs on manifolds: Reference request
I recently became interested in parabolic PDEs of order 4 on surfaces. However, I have a very little background in parabolic PDEs. I discovered Lunardi's book (Analytic semigroups and optimal regularity in parabolic problems) where some references are given but only for PDEs defined on open sets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Is there any reference where standard properties of high order parabolic equations on closed manifolds are proved? By standard, I mean properties such as existence of solutions, regularity, convergence to the initial data, etc...
